# Operator Overloading Failure in C++

Tags: c++

I defined a Fraction class as following, overloading the "=" & "+" operators.

I made this program as simple as possible to show the problem.

```
#include <iostream>

class Fraction {
private:
    int nominator;
    int denominator;
public:    
    Fraction ();
    Fraction (int, int);

    Fraction & operator = (Fraction &);

    friend Fraction operator + (Fraction &, Fraction &);

    // static function:
    // find the Greatest Common Divisor of two numbers
    int static GCD(int x, int y);

};

int Fraction::GCD(int x, int y) {
    if (y == 0) {
        return x;
    } else {
        return GCD (y, x % y);
    }
}

Fraction::Fraction () {
    nominator = NULL;
    denominator = NULL;
}

Fraction::Fraction (int num_1, int num_2) {
    int divisor = Fraction::GCD (num_1, num_2);
    nominator = num_1 / divisor;
    denominator = num_2 / divisor;
}

Fraction & Fraction::operator = (Fraction &A) {
    nominator = A.nominator;
    denominator = A.denominator;
    return *this;
}

Fraction operator + (Fraction &A, Fraction &B) {
    int nominator = A.nominator * B.denominator + B.nominator * A.denominator;
    int denominator = A.denominator * B.denominator;
    int divisor = Fraction::GCD (nominator, denominator);
    return Fraction (nominator / divisor, denominator / divisor);
}
```

And in the Main() function, I have three test case

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    Fraction frac_a = Fraction(1, 3);
    Fraction frac_b = Fraction(1, 4);

    // test 1: no compile error 
    frac_a + frac_b;
    frac_a = frac_b;

    // test 2: no compile error
    Fraction frac_c = frac_a + frac_b;

    // test 3: Error: No viable overloaded '='
    Fraction frac_d;   
    frac_d = frac_a + frac_b;

    return 0;
}
```

The question is, why "test 3" has "No viable overloaded '='" error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You defined the assignment `operator=` to take an lvalue reference as argument, but tried to pass it a temporary. Temporaries only bind to **const** references or rvalue references.

You should read up on how to overload operators in a usable way, e.g. the same problem occurs with the nonconst lvalue references accepted by your `operator+`.

That means, use `Fraction& operator=(Fraction const&)` and `Fraction operator+(Fraction const&, Fraction const&)`.

Comment: Shameless plug: [I've written a blog post series about operator overloading](http://arne-mertz.de/2015/01/operator-overloading-common-practice/), including a [class for rational numbers built with boost.operators](http://arne-mertz.de/2015/02/operator-overloading-introduction-to-boost-operators-part-2/)

Answer (score 2):

Your assignment operator is declared to take a reference to a non-const `Fraction`. Your addition operator returns by-value, so you are trying to assign a temporary to `frac_c`. Temporaries can not bind to non-const references.

The fix is to make your assignment operator take by const-reference:

```
Fraction & operator = (const Fraction &);
```

Comment: You can also add `Fraction & operator = (Fraction &&);`

Comment: @Jerome you could, but it doesn't really make sense in this case as a move from a fraction would just be a copy.

Comment: Why? That would require maintaining two functions when you only need one.

Answer (score 1):

That's because your `operator=` can't bind to temporaries.

You should define it like this:

```
Fraction & Fraction::operator = (const Fraction &A)
```

so, it will bind to temporaries and constant objects and literals.